# Sort 3 list according to their values

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have 3 lists that contain a arbitray number of doubles. Now I want to compare this lists against each others and sort them. All the list have the same length.

The relationship of sorting is:

Compare every element. The list which has more elements that greater as the other is higher ordered. I wrote an implementation for two lists:

```
public static bool isGreater(List<double> first, List<double> second)
        {
            int firstCounter = 0;
            int secondCounter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
            {
                if (first.ElementAt(i) > second.ElementAt(i))
                {
                    firstCounter++;
                }
                else if (first.ElementAt(i) < second.ElementAt(i))
                {
                    secondCounter++;
                }
            }

            if (firstCounter > secondCounter)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

But how can I adapt this code for 3, or even n lists?

Comment: You just want to know which list has more greater values?

Comment: yes, why are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using LINQ and a custom IComparer for `IEnumerable<double>`.

```
public class EnumerableDoubleComparer : IComparer<IEnumerable<double>>
{
    public int Compare( IEnumerable<double> a, IEnumerable<double> b )
    {
        var counts = a.Select( (k,i) => new { Value = k, Index = i } )
                      .Join( b.Select( (k,i) => new { Value = k, Index = i } ),
                             outer => outer.Index,
                             inner => inner.Index,
                             (outer,inner) => outer.Value > inner.Value
                                                  ? "A"
                                                  : (inner.Value > outer.Value
                                                        ? "B"
                                                        : "" ) )
                      .GroupBy( listID => listID )
                      .Select( g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() } );

        // you could also use SingleOrDefault on the collection and check for null
        var aCount = counts.Where( c => c.Key == "A" )
                           .Select( c => c.Count )
                           .SingleOrDefault();
        var bCount = counts.Where( c => c.Key == "B" )
                           .Select( c => c.Count )
                           .SingleOrDefault();

        return aCount - bCount;
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
var a = new double[] { 1, 1 };
var b = new double[] { 2, 2 };
var c = new double[] { 3, 3 };

var lists = new List<IEnumerable<double>> { a, c, b };

var ordered = lists.OrderByDescending( l => l, new EnumerableDoubleComparer() );
```

Comment: FYI... I'm using an understanding that would consider {1,3},{2,2},{3,1} to be equivalent since each has one item that is greater than and one item that is less than the item at the corresponding position in each of the other lists.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do sort() an collection of lists based on your definition of ordering. You should be able to use the standard sort and supply it your custom ordering function.

Algorithm would be something like:

1. Create a array of lists you want to sort.
2. Call the standard sort() method on Arrays, use the routine you defined above as the comparator function.

EDIT:
This algorithm should give you the max in O(M N lgN) (N lists each of size M). I know of a sligtly faster (logarithmic factors) randomized algorithm to find the max. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). I would not recommend implementing this algorithm unless you have an enormously large number of lists to process.

Answer (score 1):

First wouldn't it be easier to use a collection that is already sorted?

You can use [a Sorted Dictonary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) to do that.

With regards to your question of how to apply it to n-lists use recursion just use a collection and keep track of the last result.  This will let you compare the first and third list for example, if the result of the first iteration of your recursive function, returns the first list.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to hold counter for each list.

If you have n lists. Your array is Counter

```
 void SortLists(List<List<double>> lists)
 {
 int[] counter = new int[lists.Count];

 for (int i = 0; i < lists[0].Count; i++)
 {
     double MaxValue = double.MinValue;
     int winningList = 0;

     for (int j = 0; j < lists.Count; j++)
     {
        if(lists[j].ElementAt(i) > MaxValue )
        {
            MaxValue = lists[j].ElementAt(i);
            winningList = j;
        }
     }

     counter[winningList]++;
 }

 // sort the counter array, in effect your lists are sorted.
 }
```

Comment: but it is mentioned that all lists are equal size :), otherwise the questions doesnt hold anyway.

Comment: I just notice a problem you are comparing lists[0] to itself which is not correct behavior.  I got rid of my other comment because after taking a second look it does compare the first lists to the other lists including itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list11 = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list22 = new List<double> { 4, 5, 3 };
var list33 = new List<double> { 4, 1, 0 };

int acounter = 0, bcounter = 0, ccounter;
list11.Select((o, i) => new { a = list11[i], b = list22[i] })
    .Aggregate(0, (init, item) => item.a > item.b
                                        ? acounter++
                                        : item.a == item.b
                                            ? bcounter
                                            : bcounter++);
if (acounter > bcounter)
{
    //Do the same for list11 and list33
}
else
{
    //Do the same for list22 and list33 
}
```

**`you can refactor it and write a function for two list and call that for every pair that you want.`**

Answer (score 1):

I've eddited just a little your method and added another one:

```
private static List<double> GetGreater(List<double> first, List<double> second)
{
    int firstCounter = 0;
    int secondCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
    {
        if (first.ElementAt(i) > second.ElementAt(i))
        {
            firstCounter++;
        }
        else if (first.ElementAt(i) < second.ElementAt(i))
        {
            secondCounter++;
        }
    }

    // return the greater list instead of bool
    return (firstCounter > secondCounter ? first : second);
}


public static List<double> Greater(params List<double>[] p)
{
    // assumes the first list is the greater, then check the others
    // this method assumes you will always pass at least 2 lists

    List<double> greater = p[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < p.Length; ++i)
    {
        greater = GetGreater(greater, p[i]);
    }

    return greater;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // lists used for this test
    var l1 = new List<double>() { 1, 222, 3 };
    var l2 = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 4 };
    var l3 = new List<double>() { 11, 222, 333 };

    var l4 = Greater(l1, l2, l3); // l3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have an "outer" list of "inner" lists, and you want to sort the "outer" list. You can do that:

```
// Set up some input data
var outerList = new List<List<double>>();
outerList.Add(new List<double> { 2.0, 3.0, 3.0 });
outerList.Add(new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
outerList.Add(new List<double> { 2.0, 2.0, 3.0 });

// Sort the outer list
outerList.Sort((first, second) => isGreater(first, second) ? 1 : -1);
```

Actually, you would probably be better off changing isGreater (which can't return a "both lists are equal" result, which could confuse Sort) to a CompareLists function that returns -1 if the first argument is less than the second, 1 if the first argument is greater than the second, and 0 if they're equal. Then you could just call:

```
outerList.Sort(CompareLists);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the number of elements in each list is the same and known, here's a little example I worked up:

```
const int listSize = 6;

List<int> one = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> two = new List<int> { 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3 };
List<int> three = new List<int> { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

Dictionary<List<int>, int> lists = new Dictionary<List<int>, int>()
{
    {one, 0},
    {two, 0},
    {three, 0}
};

for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
{
    var sortedAtIndex = lists.Keys.OrderByDescending(k => k[i]);
    lists[sortedAtIndex.ElementAt(0)]++;
}

// And to show you that it works...
foreach (var element in lists.OrderByDescending(k => k.Value)
    .Select(k => k.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", lists[element]);
}
```

Comment: One thing I didn't take into account, because it's unclear in your requirement, is what if multiple lists share the greatest value for any given pass (as is the case in the final pass of my example). It would be trivial to account for this, and I leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicity of lists is an illusion - there is only one list, but each item has an attribute identifying which list it comes from.

Merge the lists, sort, then split back to their original lists.